# WebClient issue

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient

I am downloading data after every 5mins using web client but sometimes it shows a concurrency error.

```
                TimerCallback call = down;
                temp = new Timer(call);
                temp.Change(1000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

                 public void down(object obj)
    {
        if(webflag == true)
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

        webflag = false;
    }

    private void FeedsDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)

    {

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
          // some processing
        }

            webflag = true;
            temp.Change(5000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

    }
```

I am beginner so the above code must look pretty messed up. Appreciate guidance, Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the details of the exception your getting (full stack trace please)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Drew Marsh, The solution was using webClient.isbusy flag.

```
    if(webClient.isbusy == false)
    webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```